# CREATE FRAGMENT BY RANGE

Tags: database, informix

Can any one help me to create FRAGMENT BY RANGE (GENERATED_DATE) ON EXISTING TABLE IN INFORMIX?

I tried but I can't

```
ALTER FRAGMENT ON TABLE neura_biahmis_prod.episode_service_rendered_tbl INIT
   FRAGMENT BY RANGE(GENERATED_DATE) 
      INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(6,'MONTH')) 
PARTITION Q1_EPSIODE_SERVICES VALUES > DATE('2016-01-01') AND VALUES <= DATE('2016-06-01') IN datadbs1,
PARTITION Q2_EPSIODE_SERVICES VALUES > DATE('2016-06-01') AND VALUES <= DATE('2016-12-01') IN datadbs2,
PARTITION Q3_EPSIODE_SERVICES VALUES > DATE('2016-12-01') AND VALUES <= DATE('2017-01-01') IN datadbs3;
```

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING? Also, have you tried anything? Please have a look at [ASK] and [MCVE] to improve your question. Also, why the Oracle tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `PARTITION` clauses can only contain 1 inequality operator, namely the lesser operator (`<`).

As per the manual ([FRAGMENT BY clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2095.htm#ids_sqs_2095)):

```
   .-,-----------------------------------------------------------.   
   V                                                             |   
>----PARTITION--partition--+-VALUES <  range_expr-+--IN--dbspace-+--|
                           |  (2)                 |                  
                           '-------VALUES IS NULL-'
```

So you have to change your partition clauses to something like this:

```
PARTITION Q1_EPISODE_SERVICES VALUES < DATE('2016-07-01') IN datadbs1,
PARTITION Q2_EPISODE_SERVICES VALUES < DATE('2017-01-01') IN datadbs2,
PARTITION Q3_EPISODE_SERVICES VALUES < DATE('2017-07-01') IN datadbs3;
```

Be aware that with the `INIT` clause, the table will be rebuild. Make sure you have enough disk space for it (and if your database is logged this will be a single transaction, you may run into a long transaction).

Comment: thanks @luis . Is it possible that i can fragment table without dropping constraints and table .